# Fetch XML SSRS Report

Tags: dynamics-365

When i create a fetch xml ssrs report using the following fetch xml

```
<fetch distinct="true" >
<entity name="incident" >
<attribute name="ticketnumber" />
<attribute name="createdon" />
<attribute name="ssg_workedby" />
<attribute name="statuscode" />
<attribute name="ssg_trustid" />
<attribute name="statecode" />
<attribute name="ssg_requestraisedby" />
<attribute name="caseorigincode" />
<attribute name="title" />
<attribute name="createdby" />
<attribute name="ssg_turnaroundtime" />
<attribute name="ownerid" />
<attribute name="ssg_abouttofailfirstsla" />
<attribute name="ssg_abouttofailsecondsla" />
<attribute name="responseby" />
<attribute name="ssg_fixcode2cause" />
<attribute name="ssg_fixcode3owner" />
<attribute name="ssg_queue" />
<filter type="and" >
<condition attribute="createdon" operator="on-or-before" value="03-03-2020" />
<condition attribute="createdon" operator="on-or-after" value="01-01-2020" />
<filter type="or" >
<condition attribute="subjectidname" operator="eq" value="Complaint" />
<condition attribute="subjectidname" operator="eq" value="Failure in process" />
<condition attribute="subjectidname" operator="eq" value="Governance" />
<condition attribute="subjectidname" operator="eq" value="Time to resolve" />
</filter>
<filter type="or" >
<condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
<condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="1" />
</filter>
</filter>
<order attribute="createdon" />
<link-entity name="incidentresolution" from="incidentid" to="incidentid" link-type="outer" alias="CaseResolution" visible="true" >
<attribute name="actualend" />
<attribute name="subject" />
<filter type="and" >
<condition attribute="statuscode" operator="eq" value="2" />
</filter>
</link-entity>
</entity>
</fetch>
```

There are columns such as "statecode" which gets repeated 2 times. Please refer the screenshot for more information. Is there any way to reduce these two columns to only one?[image]

Comment: Did you manged to solve it? did my answer helped?

Answer (score 0):

This is because SSRS SSDT (Reporting Services) provides with State Code Value (0/1) and State Code (Active/Inactive).
In your report you are using both of them. You will need to remove any one depending on what you want.

Note: You do not need to change any thing in fetchxml, rather in Report builder just remove a column of Value or Name.